# Puppet -- if condition according to current status of machine

Tags: puppet

I am trying to write an if clause to do something according to the current status of a machine. I understand according to puppet's philosophy catalogs evaluate and push to the machines before they run in machines.

To keep consistency I would like to use puppet instead of using custom scripts (like bash). I need this kind of behavior in puppet if it would be possible.

Here's an example:
puppet agent runs every hour on a machine:
- pulling a repo to see any new commit
- searching for a specific word in the repo
    - if found: trigger some dependencies
    - if not found: trigger other dependencies

My problem:
'If clause' already had evaluated in puppet server so there is not any way to make dependencies in the desired order according to the machine status.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You have to make a Puppet Fact that shows the state of the machine you are interested in, then base your 'if clause' on that fact.
Have a look at these:
https://puppet.com/docs/facter/3.5/custom_facts.html

https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/lang_facts_and_builtin_vars.html

Comment: What "state" are you looking for?

Comment: Yes. Facts evaluate before 'if clause' so there is no way a fact assign with a new value after one of the resources is changed.
e.g. Consider the following scenarios:
A, B, C, D are resources.
A[] ~> B[] ~> C[] -- if B[] found the content then call C[]
A[] ~> B[] ~> D[] -- if B[] not found the content then call D[]
Which A[] pulls from a repo then B[] according to the newest commit, read a file and trigger either C[] or D[].

I need B[] trigger different resources after A pull the repo.

Comment: I have told may the best option would be using CI tool like Jenkins or using cron taks or even using Exec with 'refresh only'.